# query posts and custom post type with meta key

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query, meta-value

I'm trying to query all-in-one-event-calendar's custom post type ai1ec_event and normal wordpress posts in a slider on my home page. That works pretty well.

Now I want to query only the posts with the custom field value "teaser", but that returns just normal posts, not the events.

```
<?php
query_posts( array(
'post_type'=>array('post','ai1ec_event'),   
'posts_per_page' => 50,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'teaser',
        'value' => 'on'        
    )
)
);
?>
```

Even if I leave out the post type query:

```
<?php
query_posts( array(
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'teaser',
        'value' => 'on'        
    )
)
);
?>
```

it only returns posts, no events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid WP_Query is not able to fetch (Posts with custom field) or (ailec_even). You'll have to query the firs one, than the second one and merge those arrays. Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of query_posts.

I've just tried it on my local installation and this code called from index.php of twentytwelve works (brings post with title "Hello post" and ai1ec_event with title "Event" - both with custom field "teaser" with value "on"

```
$events_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => array('ai1ec_event', 'post'), 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'teaser', 'value' => 'on' ) )) );
while ( $events_query->have_posts() ) :
    $events_query->the_post();
    echo get_the_title() . '<br/>';
endwhile;
```

Have to say that both (post end event) were created by admin user - I've checked the code and there is an extensive part with custom capabilities.

Comment: I dont think, this will work. I reported the wrong behaviour. See the corrected question above. I didnt notice it first, but including the meta key query ALWAYS returns just the posts.

Comment: does your ai1ec_event contains teaser custom meta field?

Comment: Yes it does, and it is switched on.

Comment: I' just checked this taks on my local install - se modified answer above.

Comment: I checked it twice: For me that only returns posts. What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: I have it: The exact syntax has to be: `'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => 'teaser', 'value' => '"on"', 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) )` I'm not shure, if my original code would have worked, but you were a great help, so I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you!